# Creating new dictionary keys in a while Loop

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, dictionary, while-loop

I'm having a bit of an issue at the moment with adding Keys and Values to my dictionary while its in a loop. it comes up with the following error:

```
for deviceInDic in devicesDic:
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

The reason for my code is simple, its to get the values from keys within a JSON file, if the key already exists within the dictionary, simply add one to the value of that key, if it does not exist, add the Key as the device name and also add one. I seem to have hit abit of a road block here, and google isn't helping too much.

Here is a small snippet of my code.

```
devicesDic = {'duck_waxer' : 0}
x = int(0)
#y = x
y = True
while y == True:
    try:
        jdata = data["result"]["items"][0]["tagValues"]["IdDevicesMap"]["value"]
        for device in jdata.values():
            for deviceInDic in devicesDic:
                if deviceInDic == device:
                    devicesDic[device] += 1
                else:
                    print 'else'
                    devicesDic[device] = 1

    except KeyError:
        #noValues += 1
        pass

    except IndexError:
        break
    print devicesDic
    y = False
```

At the moment this is just a small loop through the first entry of the JSON file, eventually it will go through all of the entries in the JSON file.

As always, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code does not make sense: only **after** the second `for` loop, you know that the key is **not** in the dictionary.

Comment: Why don't you just use `collections.Counter`?

Comment: This loop is unncessary: `for deviceInDic in devicesDic:`. You can get rid of that loop and the `if`/`else` with just `devicesDic[device] = devicesDic.get(device, 0) + 1` and it should fix it. If the key exists, the value will be incremented by 1 each time it is found. If the key doesn't exist, it gets a default count of 0 and this is then immediately incremented by 1, so it covers both cases.

Comment: Duplicate. Search for the error message here on SO and you'll get answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not make much sense since here:

```
for deviceInDic in devicesDic:
    if deviceInDic == device:
        devicesDic[device] += 1
    else:
        print 'else'
        devicesDic[device] = 1
```

you immediately add an element to the dictionary if **one of the keys** is not equal. But it it is still possible that the key is located somewhere else.

You can solve this problem with:

```
if device in devicesDic:
   devicesDic[device] += 1
else:
   devicesDic[device] = 1
```

Or even more elegantly (without an `if`):

```
devicesDic[device] = devicesDic.get(device,0)+1
```

Nevertheless there exists a datastructure for that: a `collections.Counter`.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I see what you mean by it didn't make sense. I didn't realise that i could simply search all of the values of the dictionary with the if statement, i thought i had to go into each dictionary (as the JSON is loaded as a DIC in Python) and then compare the values. Hence the two for loops.

Once i removed them and amended my code it worked correct, thanks for the help :-) I have tried to give you an up vote but since i've got less than 15 rep points myself it doesn't show.

Comment: I will also look into the collections.Counter as i wasn't aware it was a function.

Comment: @RubenBob: it is not a function: it is a datastructure build on top of a dictionary that provides convenient ways to count things (what you here aim to do).

Answer (score 2):

You can use defaultdict. Try following code instead of yours.

```
devicesDic = defaultdict(int)
for device in jdata.values():
    devicesDic[device] += 1
```